# Torsion points on the Jacobian of a cyclic cover of CP^1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider a cyclic cover $C$ of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ branched over three points. Let $P, Q\in C$ be branch points. When is $P-Q$ torsion in the Jacobian?

If the cover is totally branched at $P$ and $Q$, then $P-Q$ is torsion, because a multiple of $P-Q$ is the pull back of a degree zero divisor on $\mathbb{C}P^1$. But this is the only result I know about the question.

Comment: If the ramification index at $P$ and $Q$ is the same you can factor the cover into one totally branched an one totally unbranched. If the totally unbranched cover is $\mathbb CP^1$, you're done, it seems like $P-Q$ will almost certainly not be torsion. This gives a slight strengthening of your result.

Comment: Will, why do you think that P-Q will almost certainly not be torsion? 


Comment: It's a pair of unbranched points. Almost all points are unbranched, and almost all differences of points are nontorsion, so almost all differences of unbranched points are nontorsion. There's a minor issue where the pullback of the divisor is not the same as the divisor, but I don't think this changes whether it's torsion.

Comment: I don't think I understand your comments Will. It is not true that every cover can be factored into a totally branched cover and a totally unbranched one. For example $y^4=x^2(x−1)^7$, where we could take $P$ and $Q$ to both lie above $x=0$ or both lie above $x=1$, so they have the same branching. 
  
If $P$ and $Q$ do not lie over the same point on $CP^1$ but still have the same ramification, then the cover is not connected unless it is totally branched.

Comment: I'm suggesting the factorization into $z^2=(x-1)$, followed by $y^2=x(x-1)^3z=(z^2+1)z^7$. Two points over $0$ would then be factored into one point over $z=i$ and one point over $z=-i$. There is only one point over $1$ since it's totally branched there. While the cover must be totally branched somewhere (which is not quite true, take $y^2=x/(x-1)$, $z^3=(x-2)/(x-3)$), it need not be totally branched everywhere.